# DefaultComboBoxModel addElement vs addAll

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

`addElement` method works very slow in `DefaultComboBoxModel` for large data. When I use `addAll` it works fine and I can see that values displayed are correct. However, in the implementation I can see that method `fireIntervalAdded` will be called multiple times in `addElement` and only once in `addAll`. Will there be any problem if I use `addAll`?

What is the use of `fireIntervalAdded`?

Comment: Did you try looking at the source code for methods `addElement` and `addAll`? Are you actually adding more elements to your `DefaultComboBoxModel`? Or are you replacing the existing elements with a new set of elements?

Comment: `fireIntervalAdded` informs all the registered `ListDataListener`s that the contents of the `DefaultComboBoxModel` have changed. Refer to [How to Write a List Data Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listdatalistener.html)

Comment: @Abra I am filtering in the dropdown using DefaultComboBoxModel. So I first remove all elements, then I iterate over all possible values and if that value contains the search pattern, I want to add the value to dropdown otherwise not. To deal with this, I can either add them in loop by using addElement or add values in list and then add the list as addAll. addAll works faster but does it has any disadvantage in this case ?

Comment: *Will there be any problem if I use addAll ?* - why would they have that method if there would be a problem? As you have noticed, only a single event is fired, which is a good thing as it will only tell the combo box to repaint itself once, or notify the listeners once, which is why it is more efficient.

Comment: @camickr Can there be any scenario where someone might want to notify the listeners for every element (from the collection and we want to display collection) we want to display in dropdown ?

Comment: You will still be notified. The listener will contain the range of all items added. Did you not download and play with the demo from the tutorial link provided above?